# AWS account - card is being billed, but which account?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a use case, a user with several AWS accounts. Not all accounts/email addresses are known, not documented, change of staff. There is a bank card that is being billed. How can I determine which AWS account is generating the billing ?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: I suggest you contact AWS Customer Service (which is different to AWS Support). They handle all billing queries.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [AWS Cost Explorer](https://aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/aws-cost-explorer/) it allows you to see detailed information about the costs. You can see what services generated how much costs, on which account, in which region and much more with filter options.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a Master / Management account if they are using AWS Organizations, and this will be able to see all child accounts through the AWS Cost Explorer Ausgefuchster mentioned.